# Scala copy case class with generic type

Tags: scala, generics, case-class

I have two classes `PixelObject`, `ImageRefObject` and some more, but here are just these two classes to simplify things. They all are subclasses of a `trait Object` that contains an uid.
I need universal method which will copy a case class instance with a given new `uid`. The reason I need it because my task is to create a class ObjectRepository which will save instance of any subclass of `Object` and return it with new `uid`.
My attempt:

```
trait Object {
  val uid: Option[String]
}

trait UidBuilder[A <: Object] {
  def withUid(uid: String): A = {
    this match {
      case x: PixelObject => x.copy(uid = Some(uid))
      case x: ImageRefObject => x.copy(uid = Some(uid))
    }
  }
}

case class PixelObject(uid: Option[String], targetUrl: String) extends Object with UidBuilder[PixelObject]

case class ImageRefObject(uid: Option[String], targetUrl: String, imageUrl: String) extends Object with UidBuilder[ImageRefObject]

val pix = PixelObject(Some("oldUid"), "http://example.com")

val newPix = pix.withUid("newUid")

println(newPix.toString)
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
➜  ~  scala /tmp/1.scala
/tmp/1.scala:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.PixelObject
 required: A
      case x: PixelObject => x.copy(uid = Some(uid))
                                   ^
/tmp/1.scala:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : this.ImageRefObject
 required: A
      case x: ImageRefObject => x.copy(uid = Some(uid))
                                      ^
two errors found
```

Answer (score 12):

I would stick with the solution proposed by Sean. I have done the same a couple of months ago. For example:

```
trait Entity[E <: Entity[E]] {
  // self-typing to E to force withId to return this type
  self: E => def id: Option[Long]
  def withId(id: Long): E
}
case class Foo extends Entity[Foo] {
  def withId(id:Long) = this.copy(id = Some(id))
}
```

So, instead of defining an UuiBuilder with a match for all implementations of your trait, you define the method in your implementation itself. You probably don't want to modify UuiBuilder every time you add a new implementation.

In addition, I would also recommend you to use a self typing to enforce the return type of your withId() method.

Comment: Doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Surely a better solution would be to actually utilise the subtyping?

```
trait Object {
  val uid: Option[String]
  def withNewUID(newUid: String): Object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting to A does the trick - probably due to the recursive definition of your case classes.

```
trait UidBuilder[A <: Object] {
  def withUid(uid: String): A = {
    this match {
      case x: PixelObject    => x.copy(uid = Some(uid)).asInstanceOf[A]
      case x: ImageRefObject => x.copy(uid = Some(uid)).asInstanceOf[A]
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe there's a more elegant solution (except - well implementing the withUid for each case class, which I think is *not* what you asked for), but this works. :)
I think it's maybe not a straightforward idea doing this with the UidBuilder, but it's an interesting approach nonetheless.

To make sure you don't forget a case - and I take it all the needed case classes are in the same compilation unit anyway - make your `Object` a `sealed abstract class` and add another cast

```
this.asInstanceOf[Object]
```

If you leave out a case for one of your case classes then, you will get a warning.